# Typescript type for react-intl component used inside same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I'm looking to use the `injectIntl` component inside the file (instead of the usual `export default injectIntl(Component)`) but having issues with typing the component.

My code looks something like:

```
type IProps = {
  name: string;
}

// I want this to be generate if decide to sent through different props.
type SFCIntl<T> = SFC<WithIntlProps<WrappedComponentProps<any> & T>>;

const Name: SFCIntl<IProps> = injectIntl(({intl, name}) => {
  return (
    <div>{intl.formatMessage({id: name})}</div>
  );
});

const Title: SFC = () => {
  return (<Name name='t.name' />);
}
```

The above would produce an error `name does not exist on type 'IntlShape'`. What would be the correct type to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You have a functional component though, so I would suggest that you use the `useIntl()` hook. The `injectIntl` is for a class component.

If you still want to use the hoc you will need to use the `WrappedComponentProps` for the types, eg:

```js
import { injectIntl, WrappedComponentProps } from 'react-intl'

type IProps = {
  name: string;
} & WrappedComponentProps

const Name = injectIntl(({intl, name}:IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>{intl.formatMessage({id: name})}</div>
  );
});

const Title = () => {
  return (<Name name='t.name' />);
}
```

using a hook would look like this

```js
import { useIntl } from 'react-intl'

type IProps = {
  name: string;
} 

const Name =({ name }:IProps) => {
  const intl = useIntl()
  return (
    <div>{intl.formatMessage({id: name})}</div>
  );
};

const Title = () => {
  return (<Name name='t.name' />);
}
```